# type error for rule in yacc

Tags: yacc, lex

I wrote the following code as a part of my yacc file.

```
 %{
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <math.h>
  FILE *fp;
  %}

  %token  LINE CIRCLE POLYGON
  %token CENTRE RADIUS WITHIN
  %token    END 

  %union
  {
  char *string;
  int number;
  }

 %token <number> NUM
 %token <string> CORDINATE 
 %start  Input
 %%

  Input:

         | Input Statement
         ;

 Statement :
         END     
         | LINE CORDINATE CORDINATE END {fprintf(fp,"\n\\newline\n\\psline%s%s\n",$2,$3,$2,$3);}
         | SCirc END
         | POLYGON Mcords         {fprintf(fp,"\n\\newline\n\\pspolygon%s",$2);}
         ;

 SCirc  :
          CIRCLE RADIUS NUM CENTRE CORDINATE {fprintf(fp,"\n\\newline\n\\pscircle%s{%d}\n",3*$3,3*$3,$5,$3);}
         | CIRCLE CENTRE CORDINATE RADIUS NUM   {fprintf(fp,"\n\\newline\n\\pscircle%s{%d}\n",-2*$5,-2*$5,2*$5,2*$5,$3,$5);}
;
Mcord   :
          CORDINATE CORDINATE CORDINATE {$$ = strcat(strcat($1,$2),$3);}
         | Mcord CODINATE       {$$ = strcat($1,$2); }
        ; 

%%

int yyerror(char *s) {
      printf("%s\n",s);
  }

int main(void) {

/* some stuff */
yyparse();
fprintf(fp,"\\end{pspicture}\n\\end{document}");
fclose(fp);
}
```

and i end up getting an error as

---

parser.y:41.42-43: $$ of `Mcord' has no declared type

---

I mean, the following example works correctly where $$ ends up as a number

```
             Expression :
                          Number    {$$ = $1;}
                        | Expression '+' Expression  {$$ = $1+$2;}
```

I want Mcord to be as a concatinaiton of many CORDINATE.
How do I do that? 
Is there any way of defining type for rules too?

Comment: @PulkitJain Sorry, I rolled back the edit you made to the question. You have basically replaced the question with a completely different one. Please start a new question instead of replacing an existing one. Thanks a lot! You can retrieve the text you entered by looking at the version history. Find the "edited" icon and click on the time above the last editor's name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, nonterminal symbols have to be declared has having a type using `%type <...>` rather than `%token <...>`.  Do you not have a good reference manual for Yacc? The GNU Bison manual is quite good, even if you're using some other Yacc.

Comment: I found an other way out. Well Thanks Kaz.